# InjectMocks to deeper levels

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, autowired

*Any suggestions for a better title are welcome.*

I have some beans as follows:

```
public class ClassA {

    @Autowired
    ClassB b;
...
}
```

and

```
public class ClassB {

    @Autowired
    ClassC c;
...
}
```

**I want to write a test and mock the ClassC instance inside ClassB. How do we do that?**

One cumbersome example that works:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
 public class ClassATest {

    @InjectMocks
    ClassA a;

    @InjectMocks
    ClassB b;

    @Mock
    ClassC c;
...
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        a.setB(b);
    }
}
```

is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: is the test an integration test? Means do you load the context?

Comment: @Patrick i guess it s pure unit testing. i donT have anything related to "@ContextConfiguration"

Comment: How can you autowire ClassA without having the context? Do you have any annotation on your class?

Comment: @Patrick right. i updated the question with my test class annotations, if it helps

Comment: ah.. my mistake, it was @InjectMocks instead of @ Autowire on ClassA a;

Comment: if you load the context you do not need any mocking. You will load the full context and all your beans are available. So just autowire the stuff. If you just want a jUnit test without the context mocking is necessary. So what do you want to do?

Comment: using `@InjectMocks` is not a good practice to begin with. On top of that if you have multiple level of InjectMocks it is even worse. I suggest you refactor your code, to use constructor injection instead of Field Injection which would eliminate the need for InjectMocks

Comment: @pvpkiran i think you are right. @ Patrick i need to mock the behavior in this case (Class C is an actual api call)